# What is / how do you set the classpath for swagger2markup?

Tags: classpath, swagger, markup, asciidoc

I'm a tech writer documenting an API written in Swagger YAML.

swagger2markup is distributed as a .jar file. The [docs](http://swagger2markup.github.io/swagger2markup/1.3.1/#_getting_started) say to add the library to my project's classpath.

I find no classpath setting or .jar files in the Swagger projects, nor is there a classpath environment variable, though npm start works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for my environment I should have been using swagger2markup-api.